# How can I list Forum Categories with its topics in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am building a forum in laravel. I want to list each forum category with its topics as so:

```
Category 1
    -Topic 1 
    -Topic 2 
    -Topic 2
Category 2
    -Topic 1
    -Topic 2
    -Topic 3
But I am getting this in stead
Category 1
  -Topic 1
Category 2
  -Topic 1
```

**This is my select query in my controller**

```
$this->categories = DB::table('forum_categories')
        ->leftjoin('forum_topics','category_id','=','forum_categories.id')
        ->leftjoin('forum_posts','topic_id','=','forum_topics.id')
        ->orderby('category_name','ASC')
        ->get();
```

**This is my Forum_categories model**

```
    public function forum_post()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Forum_topic','category_id');
  }
```

**My Forum_topic model**

```
public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Forum_post','id');
    }
Forum_post model
public function topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Forum_topic','id');
    }
```

I have also tried join for left join with similar results. Any assistance please.

**My view**

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<h2> {{$category->category_name}}</h2>
-<p>{{$category->topic_subject}}</p>
@endoforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Topic should actually have a `belongsToMany('App\Forum_topic', 'id');` relationship in this case.

Also, use Eloquent instead, it's a cleaner more powerful solution in this case.

1. Make sure your `Models` extends `Eloquent`
2. If your table name does not match the model name, declare it thussly in your class: `protected $table = "my_table";
3. Add a `protected $with = ['topic'];`

Now your Category queries will always contain a connection to their
    topics so you can access it like so:

```
$category->topics
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. I am sorry I just posted part of my models. All my model extends Eloquent.The naming of my models and the table they represent is ok. Forum_category model points to forum_categories table for example.Thanks also for pointing out the mistake I had made in Forum_post model. But still the result is the same. Only one topic is listed under each category.

Comment: Well sure, the way your data is now that's going to be the case.

Comment: But why. some categories have more than one topic but only one is shown. I have tried to use another foreach loop inside each category but unfortunately this did not work.There is something am getting wrong but I dont know what.